# How to pass a color value from one to another page in windowsphone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a color palette in one XAML page. I want to pass the selected colour to another xaml page? As it is a color, string value is giving error, string cannot be converted to System.windows.media  Can anyone help me in this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You'd pass it the same way you'd pass any non-string value.
There are 2 options:

1. Store it in an object with a global scope, so both pages/VMs can access the property.
2. Serialize the object and pass the serialized version. Because a `Color` does not support serialization directly you'll have to do this yourself. I'd do it by getting the `A`, `R`, `G` & `B` values of the color and writing them to a (probably delimited) string. Then constructing a new Color instance from the values, on the other page, using [`FromArgb()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromargb%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I will try according to this. Can you explain a bit more on getting the A R G B values.

Comment: @shri If you have a color object these are just properties on that object. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color_properties(v=VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could also temporarily store it in the State cache.

Have a look at PhoneApplicationService.State

This is accessible from all your pages.